# Android start and bind a service from a GCM Receiver

Tags: android

Is there any way to start and bind a service from a WakefulBroadcastReceiver onReceive?

If I call bind on the service I get an Exception.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot bind to a service from a receiver. The receiver is short-lived, and disappear very quickly (as soon as the end of the onReceive method finishes)

Comment: yes I know, any workaround on this?

Comment: Follow [the instructions for using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html), and have it call `startWakefulService()`. Move your business logic into your `Service`, and have it call `completeWakefulIntent()` when the work is done.